# MongoDB - get documents between dates using ObjectID

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongo-shell

As the title said, I want to get documents between 2 dates using the ObjectID. In mongoose I use `_id: { $gte: ObjectID.createFromTime(new Date("2019-01-01")) }` but I can't figure it out how to construct this query on mongo shell. There is a post on StackOverflow which lists different queries on mongo shell and mongoose but I can't seem to find that post. Does anyone know how to do the same query on mongo shell? Thanks.

**UPDATED**

Since I have already found the solution, does anyone know why the method names are different in mongo shell and mongoose? This really causes confusion sometimes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out, it's `_id: { $gte: new ObjectId.fromDate(new Date("2019-01-01")) }` on mongo shell